# Android - timer in service

Tags: android, timer

I am implementing service which will check web each 30 minutes and if there is new version of a program it will prompt download and install. My question is, how to determine in method onStart that I want to check some web location each 30 minutes from now?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Doing something every 30 minutes would be done using the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).
2. Waking the device up every 30 minutes is bad for battery life. Don't do it.
3. On Android 2.2+, you could consider using a network tickle if you really need to know about updates right away.
4. It will prompt and install? While the device is powered down? So at 3am in the morning, the app will wake up and tell me that there's an update ready for me? Why don't you just check for updates when the app is started?

Comment: ad 4. I don't want to wake up device, I want to periodicaly check, there is a new version and prompt download. It cannot be when app starts because new version can came up while I am running my app, thats why I want to make service. ad 3 I am program app for 2.1+ so I have to find some universal solution

Comment: How do you prompt a download if the phone is turned off? Are you planning to copy the same behavior of the Android Market? Will your app not be available on the market? And I was hoping that item 2 is reason enough for you not to pursue a background timer. Is this going to be an app for the general public?

Comment: It is goint to be an app for business users, not available on Market. I want to make service which is running, while app is running and check the updates, if there are - then download in Android top bar (don't know how to access it), and then prompt installation. Checking for new version should be made periodically

Comment: Well, like I said, the proper way would be to use the AlarmManager to check every 30 minutes, and then use the NotificationManager let the user know (what you call "top bar"). This is totally inappropriate for a general-use app, but if this is a specialized app and you know what you're doing, go ahead.